where are drafts stored, are drafts autosaved as I write?
I just spent 10 minutes preparing a question and made the mistake of double clicking on an image hoping an edit tool might come up to crop it. It just loaded the picture file raw into the widow so I went and did cropping in Finder Markup tool and came back. Lost the tab I was working in for a while and then closed the image tab by mistake which was actually the page I had spent 10-20 minutes preparing a draft in. I clicked undo tab close and got the time back and then clicked "Back" to go back to the "Ask a Question" pageboy all of my draft was now gone.
In Microsoft Word for instance I no where to find the autosaved text filed to recover most of my work. I don't know if such a thing exists in Stack exchange tools, but it should. I can't imagine I'm the first to lose 10-20 minutes of very boring documentation work to ask a question here.
Thanks

If you spent 10 minutes writing the question, it should have auto-saved. What happens if you go to the main page directly (not via the back function of the browser) and click "Ask Question" again?

sorry I lost track of this at the time! @nohillside

I guess the tag (drats) created in this question was probably supposed to be called (drafts).
I do not have sufficient reputation to edit on meta - that's why I'm posting a comment instead.

Edited questions and answers should auto-save every 45 seconds, see the accepted answer on Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting. To get a question draft back, just click on "Ask Question".

thanks for the prompt response. I noticed the green "Saved" text appearing  just now as ai wrote a new draft. and a red "delete draft" text button next tot he Post Question button. I never did find the draft of the question I lost so I retyped it all.

from the accepted answer in  question linked to above: "If you start asking a question, but do not successfully submit, you will see your last saved question draft the next time you visit the ask a question page.".
ok fine, that's was what I expected but it never appeared. Not in the Ask Different meta new question page which I mistakenly restarted afresh on and not in the Ask Different New Question page I just submitted from. I guess it works most of the time :-) Could have been me accidentally opening the image file in the browser tab, closing this tab, then undo close Then "back"…

@wide_eyed_pupil The back button may very well confuse the system.
